# How to checkout old version of Ionic

Tags: git, ionic-framework

I cloned the git library of Ionic. Currently it's version 4. However I want to check the source code of version Ionic3.9. It is due to there is big change between v3.9 and v4. My project is relying on v3.9.

How can I get that?

Comment: I guess you have to check the available tags and checkout the one you need. `git tag` then `git checkout whatever-tag-1.0`

Comment: you are right! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

run this:

```
git checkout v3.9.2
```

Taking revisions from https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tags?after=v0.1.3